# Cloning Sylius using composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

I am using Symfony 2.3.4

On my console i did `composer create-project sylius/sylius --prefer-dist`
Everything downloaded smoothly until it came to installing sensio/distribution-bundle

Composer throw out this error message

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://api.github.com/repos/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/zipball/4
a2c803dc8db79952ad5e71783c16178427bbc02" file could not be downloaded (HTTP
/1.1 404 Not Found)



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repos
itory-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--n
o-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

I tried :

1. Editing sylius/composer.json and modify "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*" to "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*-dev"
2. Open a shell in C:\wamp\www\sylius. Rename app/config/parameters.yml.dist to parameters.yml, run php composer.phar update --prefer-dist, still having lots of errors about MongoDb

Is there any other way to install sylius?
How can i fix this?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They fixed the issue! The problem was indeed with the Sylius build. Today i created a freshly installed Symfony2 onto my server, and did composer `composer create-project sylius/sylius --prefer-dist`

Sensio/SensioDistributionBundle installed correctly.

Steps to installed Sylius
1. `composer create-project sylius/sylius --prefer-dist` (this method download compressed file when available) or `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius`

1. make sure to enable php_info extension
2. create a database in php myadmin
3. `cd sylius`   and then `php app/console sylius:install`
4. The last part of the installation will asked you for some parameters, the default option given works fine. Accustomed it to your config

I spend 48 hours trying to install sylius finally things got better now.
There is many issues with Sylius at the moment. Check Out  And is really slow. I am still finding a way to speed things up. I took like 3 minutes to load when i clicked on Register.

If you got issued like MongDB not found, or any bundle not found, then surely there is a problem with the way you are trying to install Sylius. And Please at the moment do not `cd sylius` and `composer update`, it won't worked. I got told that they rearranged the bundle. 
You can find more detailed Click [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/324)!
Please feel free to edit this post if you feel that there is something that i haven't talked about for sylius installation. 
Thanks to Sylius Contributors!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sylius build in 0.1.0 is broken. If you want functional sylius installation you have to use dev-master version.

```
composer create-project sylius/sylius sylius dev-master
```